# C# ListView Click and Drag to Scroll the List (Like a ListBox control)

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listbox, scroll

Edit: Here is a video example to show what I want to be able to do with my ListView:
[ListBox Scrolling Video Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cWXSEjABSrI&feature=youtu.be)

If you are familiar with ListBox control you have many pages of items in a Listbox you can click and hold your mouse down, drag your cursor up/down and you can scroll through the items in the ListBox... also allowing you to scroll to the next page of items without using the scrollbar.

**Can this be accomplished via the ListView?**

Here is the scenario:
When the index of item changes in ListView it triggers a PictureBox to load an image based on that ListBox item.  So as you can imagine it is convenient to just hold down the mouse button and scroll to quickly scan through the ListBox items/pictures without having to use a keyboard.

The problem with the ListView now is that you have to click on an item one at a time.  This means to scroll down to the next page of items you also have to click on the scroll bar where as you could have just click and drag down to scroll to the next page.

Comment: Is this WPF or WinRT 8 ?

Comment: `you can click and hold your mouse down` -->> hold mouse down on **What**?

Comment: @KingKing When you click and drag your mouse outside the bounds of the box, like click dragging in excel

Comment: Exactly as Colin indicated... and when on "Single" select instead of multi-select it will just scroll down the page.  This might just not be possible with ListView default settings without doing some major coding behind a mouse event